# Issue with Syntax or Async

Tags: node.js, mongodb

hope you can help :)
I have just updated my landing ejs and gets returned the following error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier in /workspace/WDB/Yelpcamp/v6/views/landing.ejs while compiling ejs
If the above error is not helpful, you may want to try EJS-Lint:
https://github.com/RyanZim/EJS-Lint
Or, if you meant to create an async function, pass `async: true` as an option.
```

It might be something silly.. It was working all good before I have made this changes in this document , where I assume the error comes from:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>YelpCamp</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/landing.css">
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.8.3/modernizr.min.js" type="text/javascript" async></script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div class="container">
        <% if(error && error.length > 0){ %>
            <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                <%= error %>
            </div>
        <% } %>
        <% if(success && success.length > 0){ %>
            <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                <%= success %>
            </div>
        <% } %>
    </div>

    <div id="landing-header">
        <h1>Welcome to YelpCamp!</h1>
        <a href="/campgrounds" class="btn btn-lg btn-success">View All Campgrounds</a>
    </div>

    <ul class="slideshow">
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
    </ul>

<%- include("footer"); -%>
//<% include partials/footer %>
```

Comment: Can you try removing the comment-like text at the bottom of the file i.e `//<% include partials/footer %>` and compile again to see if everything works fine?

Comment: Hi @tunmee. it is resvoled. I was missing the "./partials" in the footer.
I changed the footer to this:
<%- include("./partials/footer") %>
Thank you for your help

Comment: I believe that's an issue with how you are referencing the footer ejs file. Where is the footer file located relative to the root of your views folder?